# How does one enable remote listening with rsyslog?

Tags: debian, syslog, rsyslog

I'm configuring a Debian Squeeze server to receive syslog from some appliances, but rsyslog is refusing to listen to UDP 514.

The closest I have been able to get from it is to make it listen to TCP 514 with `-c2 -r -t514`. I haven't found any combination of parameters that got it listening on UDP.

Squeeze's rsyslog version is 4.6.4-2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$ModLoad imudp.so
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Then in your rsyslogd start options (`/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog` on RHEL-based distros, not sure where it resides in Debian-based ones), you need to add `-r514` to `SYSLOGD_OPTIONS`.

Comment: The option `-r` is deprecated on Debian's version.

Comment: And now that you mentioned it, I can clearly see these lines commented close to the top of `rsyslog.conf`. Shame on me.