# Remote rsyslog on Debian

Tags: debian, rsyslog

How does one enable remote listening with rsyslog (on Debian). Forgive what seems like a super basic question, but all the docs I'm finding about it seem to apply to older versions in which one would simply add a -r to the config options. The /etc/default/rsyslog.config tells me that -r is deprecated, but it does not state what the current method is.

I looked at this:
[How does one enable remote listening with rsyslog](https://serverfault.com/questions/257147/how-does-one-enable-remote-listening-with-rsyslog) which has a comment about -r being deprecrated, but again, no mention what replaces it.

I confirmed that nothing is listening on port 514 on my server at the moment.

(My goal is to log server traffic through an Airport Extreme router.)

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have read that other question, did you not actually read the answer?

Comment: Do not fear the manpage. It will lead you to many glorious victories.

Comment: Zoredache, I did see it, but I guess I didn't want to believe that a one character flag had been deprecated and in its place, we get 32 characters of configuration.

Comment: @MDMarra Sites such as this exist because man pages are generally very poorly written. I can also vouch that rsyslog.com/doc is a mess of obsolete examples with little actual documentation.

Comment: @AaronCopley except for the fact that the correct answer for this came directly from the manpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyslog.conf) for the rsylog.conf (or rsyslog.config) file? It says:

> **Modules**
>   ...
>   *imudp*
>
> Input plugin for UDP syslog. ***Replaces the deprecated -r option***. Can be
>   used like this:
>
> `$ModLoad imudp`
>   `$UDPServerRun 514`
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks, but when I run: `sudo service rsyslog status` I get:

 `imudp not found` 
If I put in the path to imudp.so, the only result of "locate imudp", I get 
`Permission denied`

Comment: And when I chmod +x imudp.so and try to run the service status, I get a seg fault.

Comment: @TonyAdams Please don't go randomly chmod'ing things executable and trying to run them. You will create a very large mess that you have to clean up later. A shared object library (`.so` file) is not an executable program, and cannot be "run" as if it were one - it must be *loaded* by applications that know what to do with it.

Comment: You need to spend some time with the rsyslog documentation.  Specifically look up the [ModLoad directive](http://rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_modules.html/rsconf1_modload.html) & note that you can specify full paths to modules (why the module was not found in your installation is another problem that you should take a look at - you may have installation or configuration issues with your copy of rsyslog...)

Comment: Thanks. I specified a path using $ModDir  and now I'm getting 
`/etc/default/rsyslog 9: /usr/lib/rsyslog/: Permission denied`
The /usr/lib/rsyslog directory is 755